# How can you redirect a subdomain to a specific page using AWS Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I want to make it so `blog.mmatt.net` redirects to `mmatt.net/blog.html`

Right now `blog.mmatt.net` redirects to `mmatt.net/blog.html/`, for some reason, GitHub pages doesn't like it when you have the slash at the end, is there any way to either

1. remove the slash
2. redirect some other way

I'm currently using [this guide by Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/).

Comment: You can't do this using route 53.

Comment: @Marcin any suggestions on how to do this elsewhere?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve your problem with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Route 53 does not support HTTP redirects, as some other providers do. As far as I know, the only way to achieve this is to use S3 and CloudFront. Solution would be something like:

1. Create CF distribution
2. Set it as target in Route 53 ( using Alias)
3. Set default root object in CF to point to the 'page' in S3 (an S3) object.

Best, Stefan